In the DGK Cryptosystem, how hard is it to recover g, if we have knowledge of the private key?
Given the knowledge of the values for $v_p$, $v_q$, $n$ and $u$, and knowing that $g^{u*v_p*v_q} \mod n = 1$, how hard is it to compute the value of $g$? My assumption is that it is as hard as the RSA problem where we are trying to find the value of $m$, given that we have knowledge of the public key and the ciphertext $c = m^e \mod n$.
Is my assumption correct? Or if not, where am I wrong?

In the Damgaard, Geisler and Kroigard comparison protocol there is not enough information to determine $g$ nor $h$ from the private key alone.
To see this note that $g$ is an element of order $u\cdot v_p\cdot v_q$ where $u$, $v_p$ and $v_q$ are all primes and $h$ is an element of order $v_p\cdot v_q$. Note then that $g^a$ is also an element of order $u\cdot v_p\cdot v_q$ provided that none of $u, v_p, v_q$ divide $a$ (similar for $h$). It follows that there are $(u-1)(v_p-1)(v_q-1)$ possible value of $g$ and $(v_p-1)(v_q-1)$ values of $h$ which are equally valid public keys to associate with the same private key.
Finding one example of these (either a possible $g$ or a possible $h$) is sufficient to factor $n$ (breaking RSA is not known to be as hard as factoring). To see this, observe that one could easily compute $g^{uv_p}\mod n$ which would be divisible by $p$ but not $q$ (or similarly $h^{v_p}\mod n$). A GCD calculation would then recover the prime $p$.

Thank you for the detailed explanation
